# The robot's actual behavior/tasks?

Tags: ros, executive-smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had a look at `smach`. It's promising when it comes to defining what the robot shall actually do on a high abstraction level. But it seems to me that `smach` has kind of fallen asleep. Is it actively maintained or even developed further? The last commit on GitHub was made on 4th of August, 2013. There are several open issues. And it seems that `smach_viewer` isn't working with ROS Hydro which is the greatest pity since I could really make good use of a visual representation of what I've been doing (if not for documentation purposes).

Are there any alternatives to program behaviors and activities as comfortable as `smach` that are actively maintained, alive and kicking?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96731/the-robot%27s-actual-behavior/tasks?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `smach` is still under active development. Latest changes have been committed during the last 30 days. `smach_viewer` is available from hydro-devel branch of [ros-visualization](https://github.com/ros-visualization/executive_smach_visualization.git). you may have to install the `ros-hydro-xdot` package if you are using Ubuntu 12.04.

Alternatives would be interesting of course and if someone knows of one or two I would like to read and learn about them.

---

Originally posted by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) with karma: 206 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0